# how to add multiple arrays in an array like this in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
array = [[val1, val2, val3], [val1, val2, val3], [val1, val2, val3]]
```

I am trying to do:

```
[[val1+val1+val1], [val2+val2+val2], [val3+val3+val3]
```

I am trying to find a Ruby method that makes it more easy and less messy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transpose the array using [`Array#transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose), then use [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to get sum of each row:

```
array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
array.transpose.map { |a| a.inject :+ }
# => [12, 15, 18]
```